# Convert int into a generic template type

Tags: c++

I have the following function in `TreeWrapper.h`:

```
template<typename Key, typename Data, class Compare=std::less<Key>>
class TreeWrapper{
// .............
public:
void addNode(Key &key, Data &data) {
    currentAVLTree.addNode(key, data);
}
```

I would like to use the following command:

```
currentGroup.addNode(group, group.getTotal());
```

But `getTotal` returns `int` and not `Data`. Is it possible to convert it somehow? I thought that `Data` is a generic type that get anytype. Why it does not work?

**EDIT**:

In `TreeWrapper.h` the important part:

```
template<typename Key, typename Data, class Compare=std::less<Key>>
class TreeWrapper {
    AVLTree<Key, Data, Compare> currentAVLTree;

public:
    void addNode(Key &key, Data &data) {
        currentAVLTree.addNode(key, data);
    }
};
```

In the `AVLTree.h`:

```
template<typename Key, typename Data, class Compare=std::less<Key>>
class AVLTree {
    Compare keyCompare;
    AVLNode<Key, Data> *root;
    int length;

public:

    bool addNode(Key &key, Data &data) {
        // impl
    }
};
```

In the `GroupWrapper`:

```
class GroupWrapper {
private:
     TreeWrapper<Group, Group, compareGroup> currentGroup;
public:
    void addGroup(Group group) {
         currentGroup.addNode(group, group.getTotal());
    }
};
```

But I get an error: `Parameter type mismatch: Expression must be lvalue` on `group.getTotal()` and it suggests to change `Data` to `int`. Why?

Comment: We can't tell from the code you've shown.  `Data` could be a class, typedef, or template parameter.  Include an [mre] in your question.

Comment: what is `obj` ? Please provide a [mcve]. `TreeWrapper` is just a template, you need to instantiate it to create an instance, still only you know what type `Data` actually is

Comment: if group is Group, and Group::getTotal() returns int, then you'd better declare your instance TreeWrapper<Group, int> obj; Although that doesn't feel like a great key for looking up those int data points. It seems like you could just call getTotal() and skip the tree entirely.

Comment: I just want to set `int` into the `Data`. why it is not possible?

Answer (score 2):

> I thought that `Data` is a generic type that get anytype.

Not quite. It is true that `Data` represents a generic type, but that view holds only when defining the template. When a template is used, it is instantiated. Part of instantiation involves providing concrete replacements for the generic template parameters. For that instantiation, the replacement is fixed, no longer generic.

For example, look at the declaration of your `TreeWrapper` template.

```
template<typename Key, typename Data, class Compare=std::less<Key>>
class TreeWrapper
```

One way to use and instantiate this template is with a line like:

```
TreeWrapper<Group, Group, compareGroup> currentGroup;
```

Effectively, this takes the `TreeWrapper` template and replaces every instance of "`Key`" with "`Group`", every instance of "`Data`" with "`Group`", and every instance of "`Compare`" with "`compareGroup`". The result is the definition of the type of `currentGroup`.
Consequentially, the signature of `addNode` becomes the following:

```
void addNode(Group &key, Group &data)
```

You can try to call `currentGroup.addNode(group, group.getTotal())`, but since `getTotal()` returns an `int` (not convertible to `Group &`), the signature does not match.

A solution for (just) this call is the suggested change of `Data`'s concrete replacement. If you were to use

```
TreeWrapper<Group, int, compareGroup> currentGroup;
```

then the signature of `addNode` would be

```
void addNode(Group &key, int &data)
```

and the call to `currentGroup.addNode(group, group.getTotal())` would almost<sup>*</sup> match. However, this would presumably mess something else up, unless you had decided to use `Group` as the tree's data type without understanding what type of data the tree would hold.

---

<sup>*</sup> "Almost" because this would bind a temporary to a non-const reference. Since `addNode` sounds like it has no business changing either of its parameters, they should be constant references (or non-reference values), which would then make your call work.

```
void addNode(const Key &key, const Data &data)
```

This should be done in both `TreeWrapper` and `AVLTree`.

Comment: Actually, `addNode` should take its arguments by value then move the arguments into the `currentAVLTree.addNode` call. That way, you support passing in of temporaries, of move-constructed lvalues, and of normal lvalues, all in the same way and without any loss of performance (unless moving is not practical for types that you envisage here). Your way (and the OP's way) mandates a copy in every case.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit When I wrote "should" I meant in terms of correct semantics, not in terms of optimizing performance. Without the definition of `AVLTree::addNode` it's just a guess that it needs a copy of its arguments (a very good guess, but still a guess). Without the definition of `Group`, it's just a guess that move construction is relatively cheap. I'd rather not try to optimize based on guesses. If you want to write an optimized version of the question's incomplete code, you are welcome to add your answer to this question.

Comment: Broadly speaking nothing you've said is wrong, but still, passing by value should be the "default approach". Only when you've profiled and discovered a problem should it be changed perhaps. But a const ref is never better, so it's pointless to write/teach it that way. tl;dr this is not about "optimising", it is about writing idiomatic code from the start.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing non-const reference, which is why it complains about lvalue, which means a value which can be on the left side of an assignment. A function call needs to return a reference if you want to put it on the left side, and yours returns just plain int.

Changing *getTotal* to return a reference would probably be a very bad idea, so two solutions remain.

Add const at least for data:

```
bool addNode(Key &key, const Data &data)
```

Or pass a value:

```
bool addNode(Key &key, Data data)
```

Consider same changes for key.